# How to determine the MAP for an RNAV MDA approach?

Tags: non-precision-approach

[image]

On this RNAV approach plate, what is the missed approach point for the LNAV MDA approach? How do you arrive at this answer?

Answer (score 5):

The Missed Approach Point (MAPt) is at the runway threshold. The other reference you will see on this RNAV chart is the [Visual Descent Point](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/#ifpprofileview) (VDP), at 1.1NM RWY05R, which is at the Minimum Descent Altitude (MDA).

> The concept of VDP was developed by the FAA to encourage pilots to decide to initiate a missed approach prior to reaching the MAP, in a situation where the runway or its environment is not visible at a normal descent angle. Conversely, if the runway is visible at the VDP, the pilot may continue descent, following a standard descent angle to the runway, while being assured terrain and obstacle clearance.[5] The VDP is always located prior to reaching the MAP, and is a more useful checkpoint for making the decision whether to continue on the approach or to go around than the MAP itself.

<sup>(Source: [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missed_approach_point))</sup>

If the MAPt is intended to be elsewhere, it will be assigned its own identifier.

> "The missed approach waypoint is assigned a pronounceable name when it is not located at the runway threshold."

<sup>(Source: AIM 5-4-5.d.5(d))</sup>

[image: RNAV Approach Plate]
<sup>(Source: [www.faa.gov](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/#ifpprofileview))</sup>

Comment: How would they mark the vertical profile on a precision/non-precision approach chart if the MAP for the non-precision approach were not at the runway threshold and was not coincident with the MAP for the precision approach?   I assume the start of the dotted line would signify the MAP for the precision approach, but how would they mark the MAP for the non-precision approach (when it's not at the runway threshold)?

Comment: I would add that the visual descent point is also there to make sure you don't go below the MDA short of reaching the VDP, even if you do see the runway environment. This is to keep you from descending into obstacles short of the VDP. Suppose you are coming in at night for instance.